Laravel - Error with union and cursorPaginate
I am trying to do union with DB query builder because with models is not working the union with paginate/cursorPaginate.
I have this but give an SQL error because Laravel is not building the right query (maybe my fault, I don't known where to change)
The error is:
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nv.id' in 'where clause'
(Connection: mysql, SQL: 
  (
    select `nv`.*, `pi`.`image`, `unv`.`username`, `p`.`image` as `profileimage`
    from `posts` as `nv`
    inner join `post_images` as `pi` on `nv`.`id` = `pi`.`post_id`
    inner join `users` as `unv` on `nv`.`user_id` = `unv`.`id`
    inner join `profiles` as `p` on `nv`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id`
    where `nv`.`id` not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
    and (`nv`.`id` < 1)
    order by `nv`.`id` desc
  ) union (
    select `v`.*, `piv`.`image`, `uv`.`username`, `pr`.`image` as `profileimage`
    from `posts` as `v`
    inner join `post_images` as `piv` on `v`.`id` = `piv`.`post_id`
    inner join `users` as `uv` on `v`.`user_id` = `uv`.`id`
    inner join `profiles` as `pr` on `v`.`user_id` = `pr`.`user_id`
    where `v`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
    and (`nv`.`id` < 1)
    order by `v`.`id` desc
  )
  limit 3
)"

And that is right! I don't know WHY Laravel uses the nv.id alias where the correct is v.id...
The function code is:
public function getPosts()
{
    $viewedPostsIds = ViewedPost::select('post_id')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    $postsNotViewed = DB::table('posts as nv')
        ->select(['nv.*', 'pi.image', 'unv.username', 'p.image as profileimage'])
        ->whereNotIn('nv.id', $viewedPostsIds)
        ->orderByDesc('nv.id')
        ->join('post_images as pi', 'nv.id', '=', 'pi.post_id')
        ->join('users as unv', 'nv.user_id', '=', 'unv.id')
        ->join('profiles as p', 'nv.user_id', '=', 'p.user_id');

    $postsViewed = DB::table('posts as v')
        ->select(['v.*', 'piv.image', 'uv.username', 'pr.image as profileimage'])
        ->whereIn('v.id', $viewedPostsIds)
        ->orderByDesc('v.id')
        ->join('post_images as piv', 'v.id', '=', 'piv.post_id')
        ->join('users as uv', 'v.user_id', '=', 'uv.id')
        ->join('profiles as pr', 'v.user_id', '=', 'pr.user_id');

    $cursorData = $postsNotViewed->union($postsViewed)->cursorPaginate(2);

    return [
        'data' => $cursorData->groupBy('post_id')->flatten(1),
        'next_page' => $cursorData->nextPageUrl(),
        'has_more_page' => $cursorData->hasMorePages(),
    ];

}

Edit:
If I edit the 2nd query to match the same alias as the first (nv.) works but the second page give me 0 results:
First page:

Second page:

Edit 2: Trying with 'order by id in (...)' (for remove the union) gives me a meaningless error:
    public function getPosts()
    {
        $viewedPostsIds = ViewedPost::select('post_id')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->pluck('post_id')->all();
        $posts = DB::table('posts as p')->selectRaw('p.*,max(i.image) as image, u.username, max(pro.image) as profileimage')
            //   ->whereNotIn('nv.id', $viewedPostsIds)->orderByDesc('nv.id')
            ->join('post_images as i', 'p.id', '=', 'i.post_id')
            ->join('users as u', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
            ->join('profiles as pro', 'p.user_id', '=', 'pro.user_id')
            ->orderByRaw("p.id in (" . implode(',', $viewedPostsIds) . ") DESC")
            ->groupByRaw('p.id');

        $cursorData = $posts->cursorPaginate(2);
        return [
            'data' => $cursorData->items(),//->groupBy('p.id')->flatten(1),
            'next_page' => $cursorData->nextPageUrl(),
            'has_more_pages' => $cursorData->hasMorePages(),
        ];
    }

The error:

Edit 3:
Without the group by SAME error:
        $viewedPostsIds = ViewedPost::select('post_id')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->pluck('post_id')->all();
        $posts = DB::table('posts as p')->selectRaw('p.*,i.image as image, u.username, pro.image as profileimage')
            //   ->whereNotIn('nv.id', $viewedPostsIds)->orderByDesc('nv.id')
            ->join('post_images as i', 'p.id', '=', 'i.post_id')
            ->join('users as u', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
            ->join('profiles as pro', 'p.user_id', '=', 'pro.user_id')
            ->whereRaw('i.id = (select min(id) from post_images where post_id = p.id)')
            ->orderByRaw("p.id in (" . implode(',', $viewedPostsIds) . ") DESC");
            

        $cursorData = $posts->cursorPaginate(2);
        return [
            'data' => $cursorData->items(),//->groupBy('p.id')->flatten(1),
            'next_page' => $cursorData->nextPageUrl(),
            'has_more_pages' => $cursorData->hasMorePages(),
        ];

Edit 4:
Tried the @miken32 DB Query builder solution but gives me an error with the cursorPaginator:
"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (Connection: mysql, SQL: select `posts`.*, `post_images`.`image`, `users`.`username`, `profiles`.`image` as `profileimage`, (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM viewed_posts WHERE user_id = 1 AND post_id = posts.id)) AS viewedstate from `posts` inner join `post_images` on `posts`.`id` = `post_images`.`post_id` inner join `users` on `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `profiles` on `posts`.`user_id` = `profiles`.`user_id` where ((EXISTS(SELECT * FROM viewed_posts WHERE user_id = 0 AND post_id = posts.id)) > 0 or ((EXISTS(SELECT * FROM viewed_posts WHERE user_id = 5 AND post_id = posts.id)) = ? and (`posts`.`id` < ?))) order by `viewedstate` asc, `posts`.`id` desc limit 3)"

Without the paginator works great, but I need paginate

considering there's  no where('nv.id', '<', 1) in your query, I think this is one of cursorPaginate's quirks,

The only thing I wanted was to obtain rows, make a UNION other rows, all this paginated... Can it be that difficult?

Just two things. If you are doing UNION of selects from exactly same table, it probably can be rewritten using OR instead, no need to do UNION. The other thing... you have two queries where first select rows that are not in some set, the other select rows that are in exactly same set. So if you make UNION of those you will obviously get all rows in the table, so whats the point making two queries to select all rows from one table?

Hi @MichalHynčica, only purpose of order the row sets

Then what about using ORDER BY id IN (...) instead? You can even use the select from ViewedPost as subquery in the IN part if you want. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/57LB4WCEKRS3eZszDb4PnG/0

If you insist on using UNION then I would try to wrap it in another query and use the UNION query as subquery inside FROM part. Something like SELECT * FROM (S1 UNION S2) AS tmp. That might help to deal with issue caused by paginate because the paginate would be applied to wrapping query instead of union itself. But I have no idea how exactly to write it in laravel/eloquent.

Ok thats sound right, I will try the 2 options, I don't know how to apply that on laravel but tomorrow I will back. Thanks for the replys!

Cursor pagination doesn't work with arbitrary queries.
There are some limitations and your query is not compatible with them. It means that you should use the regular paginate() method instead.
I would do something like this:
public function getPosts()
{
    $posts = DB::table('posts as p')
        ->selectRaw('p.*, i.image as image, u.username, pro.image as profileimage')
        ->selectRaw('(exists (select 1 from viewed_posts where user_id = ? and post_id = p.id)) as viewed', [Auth::id()])
        ->join('post_images as i', 'p.id', '=', 'i.post_id')
        ->join('users as u', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id')
        ->join('profiles as pro', 'p.user_id', '=', 'pro.user_id')
        ->whereRaw('i.id = (select min(id) from post_images where post_id = p.id)')
        ->orderBy('viewed')
        ->orderByDesc('p.id');

    $paginator = $posts->paginate(2);
    return [
        'data' => $paginator->items(),
        'next_page' => $paginator->nextPageUrl(),
        'has_more_page' => $paginator->hasMorePages()
    ];
}


Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;
The problem is that this is in the second subquery, which otherwise sees only v:
  and (`nv`.`id` < 1)

On to other issues...
Each sub-select does an ORDER BY but no LIMIT.  Recommend adding LIMIT 3 to them.
The outer select does a LIMIT without an ORDER BY.  Add LIMIT 3.
For pagination to, say, page 11, change to LIMIT 33 for inner queries and LIMIT 30, 3 for the outer query.
More discussion:
https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union

You're making 3 queries here; one to get a list of post IDs, one to get posts that are in that list and another to get ones that aren't. For starters, mashing those last two together with UNION will leave you unable to tell which posts have been viewed and which have not in your controller/view. But you say in comments you only want this information for ordering, showing the unviewed posts first.
So, you can reduce this to a single (ish) query by doing the viewed check as a subquery and passing it to the ORDER BY clause.
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(['posts.*', 'post_images.image', 'users.username', 'profiles.image as profileimage'])
    ->selectRaw(
        '(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM viewed_posts WHERE user_id = ? AND post_id = posts.id)) AS viewedstate',
        [Auth::id()]
    )
    ->join('post_images', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_images.post_id')
    ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('profiles', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
    ->orderBy('viewedstate')
    ->orderByDesc('posts.id');


An Eloquent (with a capital E) solution would put you back into multiple queries on the database side and return a nested object, but would make your controller code much more concise. It would involve setting up a scope on your Post model that adds the subquery column and then sorts by it:
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Post extends Model
{
    public function scopeUnreadFirst(Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->selectRaw(
            '(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM viewed_posts WHERE user_id = ? AND post_id = posts.id)) AS viewedstate',
            [Auth::id()]
        )->orderBy('viewedstate');
    }
}

And assuming you already have expected relationships, the query would look something like this:
$posts = Post::unreadFirst()
    ->with("images")
    ->with(
        "user",
        fn($q) => $q->select("id", "username")->with("profile:id,user_id,image")
    )
    ->orderByDesc("id");


This is all untested, but should work in theory and at least give you a starting point to work with.

I tried the first way since it only performs one query, but with the cursorPaginate (which is what I need) it gives an error, now I put it into the question

@MaximilianoSosa As I explained in my answer, you shouldn't use a cursor paginator here. Use a "normal" one.

This largely depends on how the underlying functionalities were implemented and it very much seems that your exact scenario was not covered. If you insist on writing the query exactly as you do, then you will need to debug the underlying functionalities until you find the exact place where your v transforms into a v against your intention. Depending on the reason, you may plan your further steps.
However, I would not insist on writing the query exactly like you did and would explore upon other options to achieve the goal. I do not know where your v is being transformed technically into an nv, but since you have two queries that are independent of each-other, you could reuse the names, like:
public function getPosts()
{
    $viewedPostsIds = ViewedPost::select('post_id')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    $postsNotViewed = DB::table('posts as nv')
        ->select(['nv.*', 'pi.image', 'unv.username', 'p.image as profileimage'])
        ->whereNotIn('nv.id', $viewedPostsIds)
        ->orderByDesc('nv.id')
        ->join('post_images as pi', 'nv.id', '=', 'pi.post_id')
        ->join('users as unv', 'nv.user_id', '=', 'unv.id')
        ->join('profiles as p', 'nv.user_id', '=', 'p.user_id');

    $postsViewed = DB::table('posts as nv')
        ->select(['nv.*', 'pi.image', 'unv.username', 'p.image as profileimage'])
        ->whereIn('nv.id', $viewedPostsIds)
        ->orderByDesc('nv.id')
        ->join('post_images as pi', 'nv.id', '=', 'pi.post_id')
        ->join('users as unv', 'nv.user_id', '=', 'unv.id')
        ->join('profiles as p', 'nv.user_id', '=', 'p.user_id');

    $cursorData = $postsNotViewed->union($postsViewed)->cursorPaginate(2);

    return [
        'data' => $cursorData->groupBy('post_id')->flatten(1),
        'next_page' => $cursorData->nextPageUrl(),
        'has_more_page' => $cursorData->hasMorePages(),
    ];

}

and I would expect this to generate something like this:
  (
    select `nv`.*, `pi`.`image`, `unv`.`username`, `p`.`image` as `profileimage`
    from `posts` as `nv`
    inner join `post_images` as `pi` on `nv`.`id` = `pi`.`post_id`
    inner join `users` as `unv` on `nv`.`user_id` = `unv`.`id`
    inner join `profiles` as `p` on `nv`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id`
    where `nv`.`id` not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
    and (`nv`.`id` < 1)
    order by `nv`.`id` desc
  ) union (
    select `nv`.*, `pi`.`image`, `unv`.`username`, `p`.`image` as `profileimage`
    from `posts` as `nv`
    inner join `post_images` as `pi` on `nv`.`id` = `pi`.`post_id`
    inner join `users` as `unv` on `nv`.`user_id` = `unv`.`id`
    inner join `profiles` as `p` on `nv`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id`
    where `nv`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
    and (`nv`.`id` < 1)
    order by `nv`.`id` desc
  )
  limit 3
)

But, you could furthermore observe that the two queries are essentially the same and they differ only in nv.id not being in a set of ids being preferred over they being in the given set. So I would say you could modify your raw query to
  
    select `nv`.*, `pi`.`image`, `unv`.`username`, `p`.`image` as `profileimage`
    from `posts` as `nv`
    inner join `post_images` as `pi` on `nv`.`id` = `pi`.`post_id`
    inner join `users` as `unv` on `nv`.`user_id` = `unv`.`id`
    inner join `profiles` as `p` on `nv`.`user_id` = `p`.`user_id`
    order by `nv`.`id` not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8) desc, `nv`.`id` desc
  
  limit 3
)

where your where clause that was checking for nv.id not being in a set of ids is transformed into a descending order by, namely a first criteria, so your first records will be not from the posts having any of those ids if such record exist and only ordering by nv.id descendingly if both records to compare have the same membership status to the set in question.
I have therefore removed your
    where `nv`.`id` not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
    and (`nv`.`id` < 1)

because the first criteria does not need to be a select, but an order by and the second criteria simply does not make sense if you have positive ids.
So, instead of unioning the subsets of a partitioned query, I would enhance the sort. This is how you can sort by multiple criteria: How to sort a Laravel query builder result by multiple columns?
And this is how you can order by raw in a descending manner: https://medium.com/@junaidjaved248/orderbyraw-method-in-laravel-78c6eb56292d
